# How to set the error message in zod refine method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I have the following Zod schema:

```
const createApSchema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string().min(1).max(32),
    isActive: z.boolean().default(true),
    description: z.string().max(200).optional(),
    ip: z.string().refine(validator.isIP),
    accessMode: AccessModeEnum,
    apiUsername: z.string().optional(),
    apiPassword: z.string().optional(),
    apiVersion: ApiVersionEnum,
    community: z.string().optional(),
  })
  .refine((data) => {
    // check to see if AP type is snmp to force the community field
    const isSnmp = data.accessMode !== AccessModeEnumMap[AccessModeEnum.enum.mikrotikApi]
    if (isSnmp && !data.community) throw new Error('community string is required!')
    // check to see if AP type is mikrotik to force the api credentials fields
    if (!isSnmp && (!data.apiUsername || !data.apiPassword)) throw new Error('api username and password are required!')
    if (!isSnmp && !data.apiVersion) throw new Error('api version is required!')
    return true
  })
```

And the rule says, if you choose "mikrotikApi" as a value for the `accessMode` property, then the fields `apiUsername` & `apiPassword` & `apiVersion` will be required. Otherwise, if choose for example "snmp", then the field `community` will be required.

It works, however, in the last block in the chain, in the `refine` on the schema object, I am throwing errors in case of a wrong validation. It causes to exit my application. I don't want to exit the app. instead of throwing an error, I want somehow to ***set*** the error, so that I can handle it myself. I just want to specify an error message.

How to set the error message in zod refine method?

Comment: The second argument to refine is the error, or a function returning the error if the first argument returns false https://zod.dev/?id=arguments. Don’t throw

Comment: will I provide a function? then how can I use it?

Comment: can you give a simple example? I don't think I can provide a simple object or a string as the second argument, right?

Comment: The examples are right there in the documentation link. You can provide an object or a function that returns an object as a second parameter. https://zod.dev/?id=customize-error-path. You can’t provide a plain string.

Comment: I also suggest turning your one refinement into 3 separate refinements, as you have 3 potential errors. You can do it with one refinement, but I think 3 is cleaner

Comment: @AdamJenkins, I believe the only solution to this is to make them 3 refine method, right?

Comment: No, it’s not the only solution because the second parameter can be a function. But you’d have to duplicate the logic in both functions, so I think it’s really clean, simple, and testable to implement it with 3 refinements

Comment: You might want to use a [union that is discriminated](https://zod.dev/?id=discriminated-unions) on the `accessMode`, instead of `refine` with custom error messages

Comment: @Bergi, wow this one is cool

Comment: @AdamJenkins, yes that's what i was thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [docs on refine](https://zod.dev/?id=refine)

> Zod lets you provide custom validation logic via refinements. (For advanced features like creating multiple issues and customizing error codes, see `.superRefine`.)

And [the docs on `superRefine`](https://zod.dev/?id=superrefine) show you how to do more complex logic in your refinement. You just call `ctx.addIssue` to stack up issues with custom messages.

This might looks something like this:

```
.superRefine((data, ctx) => {
    // check to see if AP type is snmp to force the community field
    const isSnmp = data.accessMode !== AccessModeEnumMap[AccessModeEnum.enum.mikrotikApi]
    
    if (isSnmp && !data.community) {
        ctx.addIssue({
            code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
            message: 'community string is required!'
        })
    }

    // check to see if AP type is mikrotik to force the api credentials fields
    if (!isSnmp && (!data.apiUsername || !data.apiPassword)) {
        ctx.addIssue({
            code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
            message: 'api username and password are required!'
        })
    }


    if (!isSnmp && !data.apiVersion) {
        ctx.addIssue({
            code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
            message: 'api version is required!'
        })
    }
})
```

---

Alternatively, you may not need refine here at all. You actually have a union type here. One member of that union has some required fields that the other member does not require.

This might do the same thing and be much simpler:

```
const mikroApSchema = z.object({
    accessMode: AccessModeEnum.extract(['mikrotikApi']), // only mikrotikApi
    apiUsername: z.string(),
    apiPassword: z.string(),
    apiVersion: ApiVersionEnum,
    community: z.string(),
})

const otherApSchema = z.object({
    accessMode: AccessModeEnum.exclude(['mikrotikApi']), // everything but mikrotikApi
    apiUsername: z.string().optional(),
    apiPassword: z.string().optional(),
    apiVersion: ApiVersionEnum,
    community: z.string().optional(),
})

const createApSchema = z.union([mikroApSchema, otherApSchema])
```

Comment: I think this will work, I will try it